# sql db2 group by first day of each year

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following:

```
id        date_start       date_end
-----     ----------       --------
1a3       2001-12-12       2002-12-12
23b       2005-01-24       2008-11-02
11ad      2012-01-15       2014-13-09
19d       2015-01-23       2016-02-04
```

And I want to get the count of each person where the date range includes the first day of each year.

for example I can do:

```
select count(distinct id) from table
where '2001-01-01' between date_start and date_end
```

but I want to produce the count for all years from 2000-2015. I want to avoid manually doing:

```
select count(distinct id) from table
where '2001-01-01' between date_start and date_end

select count(distinct id) from table
where '2002-01-01' between date_start and date_end

select count(distinct id) from table
where '2003-01-01' between date_start and date_end
```

I am just having trouble visualizing the group by clause for this.If I had just year I could do:

```
select count(distinct id), year from table
group by year
```

however I cannot fit the `where '2001-01-01' between date_start and date_end` into this group clause.

can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join`.  Here is a method:

```
select y.yyyy, count(distinct t.id)
from ((select '2001-01-01' as yyyy from sys.sysdummy) union all
      (select '2002-01-01' as yyyy from sys.sysdummy) union all
      (select '2003-01-01' as yyyy from sys.sysdummy)
     ) y left join
     table t
     on y.yyyy between date_start and date_end
group by y.yyyy
order by y.yyyy;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I think using a dummy table is key here, but I would like to avoid hardcoding if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well you only have to check and count if the the year of date_start is different from the one of date_end.

```
select count(*) 
  from table
 where year(date_start) < year(date_end)
```

Comment: Hi michael - i do need to count those where the first day of the year is between the date range. for example if the date range is between 2nd day of the year and last day of the year, I do not want to count this.

Comment: Yes exactly - that is what it does :-)  When the date_start is another year as the date_end you have to have a new years day in the range. If the year is the same the SQL will not count it. Go try it...

Comment: hi Michael - yes this logic works. I have used a dummy table to use this logic on all years in one go. I'll add as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind me answering my own question. Using Michael's logic I was able to combine this with a dummy table - an idea from Gordon's answer. here is what I did:

```
with dummy(yr) as (
    select 2000 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    union all
    select yr + 1 from dummy where yr < 2015
)

select d.yr, count(distinct t.id) 
from table t, dummy d
where d.yr between year(t.date_start) + 1 and year(t.date_end)
group by d.yr
order by d.yr
```

as I say I hope the community does not mind me taking the parts of both posters answers to get the solution I was looking for. I did not want hardcoding and I think the answer I post satisfies this while using a simple piece of date arithmetic logic.

Comment: sorry but I think this is too complicated for what you want... try this:  SELECT year(date_end), count(distinct id) FROM table WHERE year(date_start) < year(date_end) GROUP BY year(date_end)

Comment: this will only count years where there the date range includes a new years day directly after the `date_start`. I wanted to include all years in the date range. for example if i had between 2000-02-01 to 2015-02-01 then I would need to include this persons in the counts for every year from 2001 - 2015. This is why I used a dummy table to populate rows for each year in the date range.